# Using jFiddle examples ina real world environmnet?

Tags: jquery, frameworks

I'm confused by the jFiddle examples and jFiddle doesn't seem to have a forum... I have tried to get several files working on my BusinessCatalyst site without much success. Part of the problem is that BC has its own jQuery and detection scripts that interfere with  external links (I think that is what is happening, esp. because BC uses its own browser detection schema for mobile, etc.).

But I am not sure I am getting all the proper files imported to my site. It appears that jFiddle is using JSON and other linked files by default, and they aren't noted in the html links.  Some scripts say onDomReady and specify a particular version of jQuery. Others are onLoad.   I tried to add onDomReady detection to one example, but it didn't seem to fix the problem....
I'm just wondering if there is a framework set of links or instructions that I need that I'm missing to apply these examples.

Comment: Do you mean [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: It's not quite clear what you're asking. Could you give a link to the fiddle that's not working?

Comment: If your web server prevents external hotlinking then including an external resource in JSFiddle linked to your web server will fail. You will have to physically copy+paste the contents of the JS files you need into JSFiddle's javascript section in order to get it working.

Comment: I think he is just trying to take the code from one or more jsFiddle examples and copy-and-paste that code into his own site. The problem is that the javascript frameworks used in each example don't necessarily play well with the js code he is already using in his site. This is going to be a non-trivial issue that will require some specific examples from the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, it's going to be a little difficult to port the examples over into a real-world production environment. It can be a real pain to integrate multiple frameworks javascript frameworks if you aren't already familiar with how each functions and how they can be configured to co-exist on a page.

jsFiddle examples can each use a custom set of frameworks or even none at all. That site is simply for try-it-out types of examples. You just set up the environment you want (e.g. select the framework you are interested in etc) and then type in your code snippets.  So there are no 'rules' that apply to all 'fiddles'. Each one is a custom example that isn't necessarily using the same set of frameworks and other configuration settings as any other. So think of each example as its own unique collection of frameworks and code.

It would probably help if you posted a link to a specific jsFiddle example you are trying to use. Also, you should be using some type of javascript debugger (e.g. FireBug etc). That will help pinpoint the source of error(s).

Comment: Thanks all, yes I mean jsFiddle.... I only started seeing it a couple of weeks ago as a link in some forums as I was trying to Grok some css menus.   I am pretty sure BusinessCatalyst's detection and in house js files are porking my hot linked files. Even if loaded onto the same page, they aren't working. I've taken down my trial

Comment: --http://joden.businesscatalyst.com/jPanelMenu-master/docs 
[17:20:53.438] The Web Console logging API (console.log, console.info, console.warn, console.error) has been disabled by a script on this page.

Comment: I can get some to work IF I don't use any of the BC CMS system: http://joden.businesscatalyst.com/MultiLevelPushMenu/index2.html but that isn't going to help me in a dynamic CSS menu environment... where I am relying upon the CMS to update menus and pages and the like